# Three-level table headers in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble getting this kind of table header format:

[image: sample table that I need to achieve]

These are my codes:

```
<table id="rogueD_tbl" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">

<col>
<colgroup span="10"></colgroup>

<thead>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"> ID </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> UNIT ID </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> UNIT/STATION </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> NO. OF POPULATION </td>

        <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup" > NR. OF FIRE TRUCK     </th>




     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup" > OPNL </th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup" > NON OPNL </th>

     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td scope="col">  BFP </td>
        <td scope="col"> LOCAL </td>

        <td scope="col"> BFP </td>
        <td scope="col"> LOCAL </td>
     </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
```

I'm trying to achieve a 3 level table header but I think I'm overlooking something that is rather simple.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/01o4wqaz/

Comment: Thank you for your response! @pbogut will it work if I use datatables? 

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20687/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-10-of-undefined

Comment: I have no idea, how about you check it with datatables documentation?